# Is it true that $ \int_{[1,\infty)} f_n\to \int_{[1,\infty)} f$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Can you please help me solve this on measure theory? My TA did not go over this. He said we are not going over this but you can do this if you want. Can someone please explain to me? Thanks.

Suppose $f_n\to f$ on $[1,\infty)$ and $|f_n(x)| \le 1 / x^2$ where $1\le x$.

Is it true that $ \int_{[1,\infty)}  f_n\to \int_{[1,\infty)} f$ ?

Comment: Do you know some limit theorems for integrals?  Can you find one that fits this situation?

Comment: Could you please give this question a better title?

Answer (score 3):

you have $|f_n (x)|\leq \frac{1}{x^2}$ , for $x \geq 1$.

By the dominated convergence theorem you have

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \int f_n =  \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n = \int f .$$ 
In the first equality was use the dominated convergence theorem